# How to define multiple hasMany relationships of same(parent) type on model?

Tags: ember.js, model, coffeescript, ember-data, ember-cli

I want to define multiple hasMany relationships on Ember Data model of parent type, but I don't have a clue how to specify inverses for this:

```
Profile = DS.Model.extend
  # ...
  friends:      DS.hasMany 'profile', async: true
  observed:     DS.hasMany 'profile', async: true
  observers:    DS.hasMany 'profile', async: true
```

It would be easy for me to handle such properties in database, however Ember Data doesn't support this. Is this possible to have this 3 hasMany relationships defined without creating another models (eg. Friend, Observer).

Error I'm getting:

> Error: Assertion Failed: You defined the 'friends' relationship on
>   app@model:profile:, but multiple possible inverse relationships of
>   type app@model:profile: were found on app@model:profile:. Look
>   at
>   http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_explicit-inverses
>   for how to explicitly specify inverses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data wants to have a foreign key on the belongsTo side so that it can wire up the models in either direction for you. Ember Data does not directly support many-many relationships hence needing a second join model.

This is pretty much in line with how you model data in a SQL database.

One of the things I dislike most with Ember Data is the fact it wants ids on the hasMany side as well as the belongsTo side. This is not a great approach when you have high cardinality relationships as it means large payloads and inefficient queries when a simple foreign key based lookup would be more efficient. It also gives the illusion that you could perhaps avoid a second model and your Profile model could just have arrays of ids for each relationship but it just doesn't work that way currently.

Comment: Exactly, but I don't have inverse specified on `friends`(no `belongsTo 'profile'` on profile) and it works as expected. I only have to add/delete record to array manually - so why it doesn't work with more hasMany's? Seems that there's lack of consistency here. I should get an error immedietaly with `friends: DS.hasMany 'profile', async: true`.

Comment: Yes you can get mixed results without having the inverse, the relationship will only be navigable in one direction and it requires manual intervention to keep relationships on both sides in sync. Ember data will secretly resolve related models via type when you omit the inverse option which is why its working for one of your relationships.

Answer (score 0):

This works for now:

```
Profile = DS.Model.extend
  # ...
  friends:      DS.hasMany 'profile', async: true
  observed:     DS.hasMany 'observer', async: true, inverse: 'observer'
  observers:    DS.hasMany 'observer', async: true, inverse: 'observed'

Observer = DS.Model.extend
  observer: DS.belongsTo 'profile', async: true
  observed: DS.belongsTo 'profile', async: true
```

However, I'm still interested if there is a way to do it without defining another model.